# Move wave texture along object with keyframes (in cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, keyframes

I want to create a wave texture on an object (which worked so far) and move it with keyframes. Therefore I created a `Wave Texture` and used `Mapping` for the orientation. The first strange thing is that I have to use `Scale` in order to achieve the correct orientation (instead of `Rotation` like I would expect). The second thing is that `Location` within `Mapping` does not seem to have any effect. Do I have the correct order of the nodes or is there something else wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the mapping node choose either "Texture" or "Point" options.
Then adjust rotation to the angle you want and then animate the location for the desired effect.
I am attaching a screen shot of how.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I additionally had to experiment with the - in my case - ``y-location``. Very slight changes made a large difference in the phase of the wave.